# Disabling "invalid argument supplied" warning for a particular foreach

Tags: php

Can I disable warnings for particular `foreach` statements and more specifically the "invalid argument supplied" warning?

p.s. I want a foreach that when passed `null`, instead of throwing an error, will just not execute.

Comment: Nope, unless you want disable all warnings. Or write your own error_handler which specifically filters this one out by examining the error text.

Comment: warnings are there for a good reason... something is wrong so fix it instead of hide and ignore. check before if `var` is an `array` or `Traversable`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternative, type agnostic, using a typecast:

```
foreach ((array)$variable as $s)
```

Would convert a NULL into an empty array, or a integer/string into an array with a single entry. This is sometimes advisable if you traverse flexible data structures (PHP is a dynamic language after all). The failure method is advisable for catching invalid data (should rather throw an error however).

Answer (score 5):

No, not even using `@` in front of the foreach (but that would be bad practice anyway).

Just do an easy `is_array()` check beforehand:

```
if (is_array($variable))
 foreach($variable.......
```

Comment: I tried putting `@` in front but it results in an error - `syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH`

Comment: Use his second suggestion, then. That's the one that got me to upvote.

Comment: @Emanuel true, I tried too, doesn't work. Will correct my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in

```
if(isset($variable)) 
{
    foreach($variable ...
}
```

works with me.